# Fastest way to read data from single MS SQL table into java under single transaction

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I need to read a large result set from MS SQL server into a java program. I need to read a consistent data state, so its running under a single transaction. I don't want dirty reads.

I can split the read using offset and fetch next and having each set of rows processed by a separate thread.

However, when doing this, it seems that the overall performance is ~30k rows read / sec, which is pretty lame. I'd like to get ~1m / sec.

I've checked that I have no memory pressure using visual VM. There are no GC pauses. Looking at machine utilisation it seems that there is no CPU limitation either.

I believe that the upstream source (MS SQL) is the limiting factor.

Any ideas on what I should look at?

Comment: Maybe you should look at what the Java tier will do with all that data.  Your proposal sounds inefficient: transfer millions of rows to the Java tier, operate on them, put them back.  Perhaps you can do that processing in the database and spare yourself the transfer.  Maybe a stored procedure or triggers on the database could eliminate the transfer back and forth.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any information to suggest that multi-threading will perform better than a single thread for your particular environment? If the limiting factor really is upstream (as you suspect) then you may just need a more powerful SQL Server machine or a fatter network pipe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Are you migrating data from SQL Server into PostgreSQL?  There should be tools to help with this.

Comment: @GordThompson well indeed, a single thread is more performant. I want to know why.

Comment: @duffymo I need to run this operation many, many times. Its an ETL job essentially.

Comment: Waste of time to write it yourself in Java.  Use an ETL tool that someone else has perfected.

Comment: @duffymo It is not a waste of time if one finds out something useful about how the underlying tech works. And besides, in my experience ETL tools / frameworks come with significant drawbacks. 

Classic stackoverflow response "You're doing it wrong"  - I blame Apple!

Comment: Certainly knowledge is never a waste of time, but moving a table from one database to another should not suffer from drawbacks.  Just a word of caution for you - you're free to ignore if you wish.  Multithreaded code is hard to write, even for smart people.  I can think of better ways to spend time, that's all.

Comment: @duffymo For my project, moving data from one table is a show stopper if its not fast enough. I'm perfectly happy writing multithreaded java code, its not hard these days. I've also considered using a spark cluster for this pipeline (so I don't write crappy multi-threaded code) but it would have the same issue as the source is the same.

Comment: Good luck, then.

Comment: "... a single thread is more performant. I want to know why." - One possible reason is that the SQL Server doesn't have to manage the transaction being distributed across multiple sessions. If a single session (thread) can keep the server busy and the data pipe full then using multiple threads will just add overhead.

Comment: @GordThompson that's a good point, but neither the server or the client seem busy. CPU utilisation ~2%, ram ~25%, disk I/O low, network low etc